# How would you display a sent message in PHP without redirecting through header location?

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-mobile, echo

I am using JQuery mobile and it has issues with loading external files - always displaying "error loading page" message. So I can't use a header location in PHP to redirect to the page after submiting a form.

How would you display a sent message underneath the submit button once it's been pressed?

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="update_beer" action="php/input_pint.php">
      <p><label for="name">Your name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="name" id="name" /></p>
      <p><label for="price">Price of a pint</label><input type="number" name="price" id="price" cols="5" /></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Update" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or 
      <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

This is the PHP that is sending all input to my database:

```
<?php
//input price_pint.php
$con = mysql_connect("hostname", "databasename", "password");
if (!$con) {
die("Could not connect." . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO price_pints (name, price)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[price]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I just don't know how to relate an echo message to my form.

Comment: why not "alert"? or msgbox?

Comment: am I missing something here or are you after an ajax solution to this problem?

Comment: use ajax to no-refresh solutions

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. And *really* don't build SQL from user input like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ajax, also you need to sql escape your inputs, else a drink like `Foster's` `Sam Smith's` ect is going to break your query.

```
<script>
$("#update_beer").submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/input_pint.php",
        data: $("#update_beer").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data=='true'){
                alert('Beer Added');
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Also Heres a better way of connecting and inserting into your database, using PDO:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databasename", 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['price'])){
        $sql = 'INSERT into price_pints (`name`,`price`) VALUES (:name,:price)';
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':price', $_POST['price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        die('true');
    }
}
die('false');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function which will insert it into database and return a flag like- true if succeed and false if something goes worng.then according to the flag echo your message.